# How to programmatically minimize ios app like in Keynote or Pages?

Tags: ios, minimize, keynote

Or Numbers app... ? If I have not been signed-in the Numbers app shows the "Sign-In Required" alert. If I touch Cancel - system minimizes the app. Is there any way to do it programmatically?

Comment: Where does this happen? Do you mean the Apple Numbers app? The spreadsheet app? I've never seen that happen. I've not even seen the "sign in required" thing. Programatically closing an app is a direct contradiction of the Apple guidelines to the point that it will get your app rejected. You really, REALLY shouldn't do this.

Comment: @Fogmeister Seems it's OS alert. "To download these app and receive future updates, you must first sign in with your Apple ID". So it is not the app future. Here is the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrbL5E2vMyQ

Comment: Ah. That's because the apps aren't actually installed. They are there as a promotional prompt to get you to install them.

Answer (score 3):

This is private method for minimize iOS App. Not for Appstore:

In Swift:

```
NSThread.detachNewThreadSelector(Selector("suspend"), toTarget: UIApplication.sharedApplication(), withObject: nil)
```

In Objective-C

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"suspend") toTarget:[UIApplication sharedApplication] withObject:nil]
```

Comment: What do you mean "not for App Store"?